# Call a method when iOS is crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that keeps checking the data, and I have implemented method for AppWillTerminate
It works fine when the app is closed by user, the data is saved before the app is closed.

However, sometimes when the app is running at the background and user switch to other iOS app, and while they are using other apps, iOS could crash.

When I say iOS crashes, I mean it goes to black screen and restart again.

And in this scenario, my app's "willTerminate" is not called, therefore, my app's data is lost.

My question is, is there a way to save my app's data before iOS crashing?

Comment: Maybe you can add some logs at app launch and termination, so when the app launches but it does not find the termination log of the previous launch, it means your app crashed last time.

Comment: However, it is theoretically impossible to make the app itself aware its own crash, which is pretty like the Turing Halting problem. I don't know if I am wrong. But without a super-process monitoring over your app, there's no way to tell that directly.

Comment: [`applicationDidEnterBackground:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:)

Comment: Save data when app enters the background. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

In your `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, add this.

`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);`

And add the following to your `AppDelegate`.

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler () {
    // method to save data
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try, however, this C language code seems having problem with accessing my Objective C properties. Do you happen to know how can I access Objective C property from C code?

Comment: @ZhangZhan Rename your **.m** file to **.mm**.  This results in a hybrid objc-c/c++ module

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);

    struct sigaction signalAction;
    memset(&signalAction, 0, sizeof(signalAction));
    signalAction.sa_handler = &HandleSignal;

    sigaction(SIGABRT, &signalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGILL, &signalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &signalAction, NULL);
}

void HandleException(NSException *exception) {
/** NSLog(@"App crashing with exception: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]); */
/* Save somewhere that your app has crashed. */
}

void HandleSignal(int signal) {
/**NSLog(@"We received a signal: %d", signal); */
/** Save somewhere that your app has crashed. */
}
```

Comment: Once ios app crash then will get stack symbolic log in the exception, after crash once you open the app again we can see that log to check where exactly its crashed.

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: @Andy : what u mean of that ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments  (I cant comment at the moment otherwise would have mentioned it there) the best way is to save the data in your 
    applicationDidEnterBackground: 
function in AppDelegate. As per apple when your app is in background it is in suspended state which means Apple can terminate it whenever it wants without notifying the app if the active app (the one running on foreground needs more resources). So your app goes from Suspended state (the state where it was put when it was sent to background) to Terminated while other apps were used, and when it becomes active again it starts from scratch, so actually its not crashing (wont raise an exception) but just being restarted if it was terminated while being in the back ground.

this is a nice read in understanding the, [App Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The issue is even the app has entered background but it is still processing data, that means, I still lost the data when iOS crashes.

Comment: When applicationDidEnterBackground is called, you have a small amount of time where you can do things, but iOS assumes that it can kill your app at any time. So yes, if you are still processing data, it _will_ be lost. Don't do it.

Comment: Its an interesting problem, something I might face soon so just for the sake of discussion, have you looked into this [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) it explains to call a mehtod with expiration if the background task is longer. Do let us know if you found a solution, would be nice to have knowledge of how to solve this issue, as I assume it would be a common one.